# Studing java: character comparing

Tags: java, character

**Exercise:** 
(Longest common prefix) Write a program that prompts the user to enter two strings and displays the largest common prefix of the two strings.

Here are some sample runs:

```
Enter the first string: Welcome to C++
Enter the second string: Welcome to programming
The common prefix is Welcome to
```

Second run:

```
Enter the first string: Atlanta
Enter the second string: Macon
Atlanta and Macon have no common prefix
```

**my answer:**

```
package chapter5;

import java.util.*;

public class Exer5_51 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first string: ");
        String firstString = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second string");
        String secondString = input.nextLine();
        input.close();

        int length = Math.min(firstString.length(), secondString.length());             
        String commonPrefix = "";

        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++) {
            if (firstString.charAt(n) == firstString.charAt(n) ) {
                commonPrefix += firstString.charAt(n);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }       
        }

        if (commonPrefix.length() != 0) {
            System.out.printf("The common prefix is %s", commonPrefix);
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("%s and %s have no common prefix", firstString, secondString);
        }

    }

}
```

***Is there anything wrong with my code?
Why I can't get the right result?.***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please remember when posting questions to include what output you are getting when running your code as well as what the expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (firstString.charAt(n) == firstString.charAt(n) ) {
            commonPrefix += firstString.charAt(n);
}
```

Should be:

```
if (firstString.charAt(n) == secondString.charAt(n) ) {
            commonPrefix += firstString.charAt(n);
}
```

You were comparing the first String to itself before.

Comment: Thanks,I must be too tired.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the firstString to itself in the if statement.

```
if (firstString.charAt(n) == firstString.charAt(n) ) { 
    commonPrefix += firstString.charAt(n);
}
```